# ReactiveHealthIndicators called multiple times when using CompositeReactiveHealthContributor

Tags: spring-boot

I have multiple health indicators in my project and I want to group them using `CompositeReactiveHealthContributor`.

I'm facing 2 behaviors I didn't expect and that I'd like to get rid of:

1. When I call the health endpoint with details enabled, I see both the composite and the single health indicators, so the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "components": {
     ...
    },
    ...
    "composite": {
      "status": "UP",
      "components": {
        "My name 1": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            ...
          }
        },
        "My name 2": {
          "status": "UP",
          "details": {
            ...
          }
        },
        "My name 3": {
          "status": "UP"
        }
      }
    },
    "custom1": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        ...
      }
    },
    "custom2": {
      "status": "UP",
      "details": {
        ...
      }
    },
    "custom3": {
      "status": "UP"
    }
  }
}
```

2. All health indicators are called 2 times

What do I have to do differently or to configure so that only the `CompositeReactiveHealthContributor` is shown when the health endpoint is called and that the indicators are only called once?

The individual `ReactiveHealthIndicator` all look like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomNHealthIndicator
    implements ReactiveHealthIndicator, NamedContributor<ReactiveHealthContributor> {

  @Override
  public Mono<Health> health() {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "My name N";
  }

  @Override
  public ReactiveHealthContributor getContributor() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

The `CompositeReactiveHealthContributor` is configured like this:

```
@Configuration
public class HealthConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public CompositeReactiveHealthContributor compositeHealthContributor(
      @Nonnull CustomHealthIndicator1 customHealthIndicator1,
      @Nonnull CustomHealthIndicator2 customHealthIndicator2,
      @Nonnull CustomHealthIndicator3 customHealthIndicator3) {
    var contributors =
        Map.of(
            customHealthIndicator1.getName(),
            customHealthIndicator1.getContributor(),
            customHealthIndicator2.getName(),
            customHealthIndicator2.getContributor(),
            customHealthIndicator3.getName(),
            customHealthIndicator3.getContributor());
    return CompositeReactiveHealthContributor.fromMap(contributors);
  }
}
```